# Unit test results not showing up in SonarQube

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube-scan

I configured a Jenkins build to run SonarQube and I see all results except code coverage.  I can see the xml and txt files in the surefire-reports dir and I also see jacoco.exec so I am puzzled as to what I am missing, which I suspect will be something super basic.

SonarQube version: 6.3.1
Jenkins: 2.46.2

Here is my SonarQube config in Jenkins:

```
# metadata
sonar.projectName=${JOB_NAME}
sonar.projectVersion = 0.1

#path to source
sonar.projectBasedDir=${WORKSPACE}
sonar.sources=src/... (removed specific path)
sonar.binaries=target/classes


#report location
sonar.junit.reportPaths=${project.build.directory}/target/surefire-reports sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=${project.build.directory}/target/surefire-reports/jacoco.exec

#testing parms
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.tests=src/test/java
sonar.language=java
```

Here is the plugin data from my POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
    <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
    <runOrder>random</runOrder>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>0.7.9</version> 
    <configuration>
         <destFile>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports/jacoco.exec</destFile>
         <dataFile>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
    <output>file</output>
    <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
         </execution>
         <execution>
            <id>report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
          </execution>

         </executions>
        </plugin>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
          </dependency>
```

Comment: can you include the maven command you are using to do your scan?

Comment: @Tim I am using the mavem goals - clean test package

Comment: i was comparing your pom to some of mine. I use the maven-surefire-plugin, not the apache one you are using (if that makes any difference). But to do the scan, "mvn -U clean org.jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://<my sonar host:9000>"

Comment: @Tim. Thanks for the input. There was a small syntax difference for the maven plugin **(org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent)** and once I fixed that, we were off to the races.

Comment: @ApolloRaptor If you are off to the races can you please provide your solution as an answer?

Comment: @Tim What version of the surefire plug-in are you using that is compatible with the new reportPaths variable? I have 2.18.1 and I think that's the reason I'm getting some warnings about the old name with my new Sonar.

Comment: I am using 2.19.1

Answer (score -1):

It could be that the report path argument should be:

`sonar.junit.reportsPath`

not

`sonar.junit.reportPaths`

Comment: Please Add some description regarding your answer. Please Explain more properly. Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: In the current version, its changed to .reportPaths from .reportsPath. You might be running an older release.